# Catch 22 - Unable to switch to frame, cannot locate element in frame that I'm unable to switch to. Ugh

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hello helpful Selenium window & frame switching guy (or girl),

Could someone please provide some window or frame switching assistance?

I'm trying to automate a basic shopping cart flow test case.  I'm using Java and Selenium Webdriver (standalone 2.35.0) to automate Firefox.  The buyer finds a product and clicks the 'Add to cart' button.  The background page is greyed out and a popup window appears.  On the popup window, there is a 'Checkout' button.  After that button's clicked, the popup is dismissed and the user can continue the purchase flow (fill out credit card & shipping info, etc.).

For the life of me, I cannot get to that popup window and click the Checkout button.  I have tried looping through window handles.  A printout of the loop shows that the size of window handles is only 1 (despite Firebug showing multiple frames/windows).  I've tried switching to the iframe by name and index to no avail.   I'm waiting at least 3 minutes for the Checkout button element to become visible.  Firebug shows that the window is #7.

Once I can switch to the popup window, I should be home free.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

```
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class TestCase1 {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.lampsplus.com/products/franklin-iron-works-hickory-point-15-inch-high-outdoor-light__09569.html");

    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println("size:" + windows.size());

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pdAddToCart']")).click();


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#aCheckOut1")));


    System.out.println("now size is:" + windows.size());

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aCheckOut1']")).click();

    //cc form info - omitted for brevity

    driver.close();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you.  The `WebDriverWait` now waits for the `iframe` to become visible, switches to the `iframe`, then clicks the element you want.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#add-to-cart>iframe")));

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#add-to-cart>iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aCheckOut1']")).click();
```

After you're finished in the `iframe`, remember to switch back out:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Richard, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  Your solution worked perfectly.  Really appreciate the help.